# Вывод идентичных записей в строку

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица и вывод из нее

`name  |  leading
title1 |  lead1
title1 | lead2`

Как сделать такой вывод

`name  |  leading
title1 |  lead1, lead2`

Надеюсь нормально объяснил.

Comment: @splash58 спасибо

Comment: не за что. удачи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select name, group_concat(leading) 
     from ... 
   group by name
```