# Соединение нескольких полей

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь в создании запроса. Суть задачи такова. Есть таблица:

```
|-----------------------------------------------|
|complekt_id | main_product | additional_product|
|-----------------------------------------------|
|      1     |   111        |       222         |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|      1     |   111        |       333         |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|      2     |   111        |       444         |
|-----------------------------------------------|
```

На выходе должно получиться:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|complekt_id | main_product | additional_product1 | additional_product2 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      1     |   111        |       222         |         333           |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|      2     |   111        |       444         |                       |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Извините, сейчас исправлю вид таблицы

Comment: Может через запятые будете отделять.

Comment: Отдельными колонками не выйдет ибо количество колонок точно должно быть известно в момент компиляции запроса. только через запятую или другой разделитель в одном поле

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520412/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83/520416#520416

Comment: Количество колонок известно. additional_product может быть только 2 для одинаковых complekt_id и main_product

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь. Подошли 2 решения. Через GROUP_CONCAT(additional_product) и этот ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/577935/215995.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С условием, что записей может быть только 2 (указано в комментариях) можно сделать так:

```
select complekt_id, main_product,
       min(additional_product) as additional_product1,
       if(count(1)=1, NULL, max(additional_product)) as additional_product2
  from Table
 group by complekt_id, main_product
```

Comment: Спасибо. Наиболее подходящее решение!

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.complekt_id
     , t1.additional_product additional_product1
     , t2.additional_product additional_product2
from tab t1
left join tab t2 on t1.complekt_id = t2.complekt_id
```

Если нужно что-то динамическое, то можно организовать в цикле по количеству UNPIVOT полей.

Comment: Если через join то вам надо доработать условия. Текущий ваш запрос вернет 4 строки с complect_id=1 и такими add1, add2: (222,222), (222,333), (333,222), (333,333)

Comment: Да, условия нужны

Comment: Во первых вам нужно в соединении условие, что t1.add<t2.add (что бы не приклеивал запись саму к себе), во вторых надо еще как то ограничивать количество строк на выходе, потому как он все равно из t1 выберет 2 строки и выдаст их обе, а нужна только одна. значит надо выбирать только такие строки для которых нет строк с меньшими add